# What custom close reasons, if any, do we need at present?

Tags: discussion

We can have up to three custom close reasons offered when voting to close a question. (More can be added by request if there is a demonstrated, pressing need.) Do we have any situations arising often enough to justify a custom close reason yet?

Note that we don't need to use these, they are there for if we find a use for them and aren't going to get taken away just because we don't put anything in them straight away!

Edit: I've removed my examples as no-one can vote on examples and they might confuse people into thinking they were already being added.

Comment: Ideally each custom close reason will link to a meta post for further explanation, so let's try to include those here too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio Agreed. However, we can always make one to describe the rationale behind each, and for policy that may sometimes be better. So I wouldn't sweat it too much if there isn't a great meta post describing the rationale behind the specific close reason yet.

Comment: Oh yes, we can write them later if needed.  I think we may have some already,  so just saying to link then if you have links handy - saves work later.  (On phone right now or would help more. )

Answer (score 11):

- Ideas Generation : This come up on a semi regular basis, and is indicated by a question that has "something happen". Often a list answer and opinion based.

Split into three answers as suggested (Feel free to add examples)

Comment: I think this one at least has received enough upvotes to warrant inclusion. Do we have a meta post that fits?

Comment: How about [this one](http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/522/2072)?

Answer (score 5):

- Plot Writing : This is fairly close to Too Localized, but at least gives a specific reason as to why we close it. Note that Writers.SE does not accept plot questions either, so this is not a redirect (which already exists)

Split into three answers as suggested (Feel free to add examples)

Comment: I think Ideas Generation and Plot Writing are almost the same thing, probably not worth taking up 2 slots

Comment: @Liath I disagree but I see your point. I think the close text needs to be different for these things though.

Comment: Wasn't there a "too story-based" close reason? If yes then this is almost synonymous.

Answer (score -4):

Is it Possible?

There are quite a lot of low quality questions where people have an idea which they want to know if it's possible. While I don't have a problem with this in particular - I've certainly as [asked them](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/29/what-factors-could-cause-a-world-to-see-northern-lights-much-further-down-the) but I think it's a trend of some poor quality questions.

- Is it possible to settle on the moon?
- Is it possible to fly to another solar system?
- Is it possible intelligent life could evolve on the seabed?

Perhaps these are already covered by "Too Broad" but it's the type of question where "I want to get the moon and I want you to work out how to do it".

Please suggest edits for a better name for this!

Comment: [tag:reality-check] is allowed, so its not a problem with these kinds of questions. I think too broad already covers this.

Comment: @Mourdos yeah, I'm not happy with the description... it was more of a style of some poor questions I don't think there's anything wrong with the question type itself!

Comment: If we have a lot of reality-check question being too broad, is it worth using a warning instead? A warning is a message that is visible to the question writer when they select the tag.

Comment: @Mourdos to be honest I think it's fine as it is, I think the reasons we have already cover it pretty well.

Answer (score -6):

- Lack of Basic Research: The official answer to this is to downvote, but I've seen a number of these and people don't seem to understand that this is SE policy that the questioner should have done some basic research before asking a question.

Split into three answers as suggested (Feel free to add examples)

Comment: ... This particular answer is a great example of what you are supposed to do with lack of basic research - the intended operation is down-vote.  (I kid for irony's sake, but this answer...shows lack of basic research.)

Comment: @Tritium21 Try reading that first line again. Its a doozy I know, but that is the bit that shows that the answer has actually been research. Suggesting doing something different to standard policy != lack of research.

Comment: Actually @Tritium21, on meta sites downvoting generally indicates *disagreement*, particularly in [discussion] questions.